# xtype of tablet view opening in mobile in sencha touch

Tags: extjs4, sencha-touch-2.1

I am using profiles in my Sencha application to detect whether a device is a desktop, a mobile or a tablet.

I have created a different view for all the profiles and named it Main. I have given xtype to all of them as xtype:'main'.

Now in controller I am adding to the Viewport xtype:'main'. It works fine for tablet but for phone also it loads the same tablet screen.

I read some posts and there it was mentioned that you cannot give same xtype to different views. But my questions is that what is the use of profiles if we cannot give same xtype to same views. Because only one Main (according to specific profile) will be loaded at a time?

Any help is appreciated.